# Implementing Parallel Payment using PayPal in android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to implement **Parallel Payment** of PayPal in Android. Paypal-android-SDK is not supporting parallel payments. While, Paypal has **adaptivePaymentSDKs** for    Java, PHP, .Net and Ruby but it's not working on Android.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to implement it through web payment using paypal on android.

Comment: How you worked with **Parallel Payment?** is there any help or link?

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal-Android-SDK has been deprecated so that isn't going to have a parallel payments solution. Adaptive Payments has also been deprecated.

There is a new solution called PayPal for Marketplaces which uses our REST API platform and is essentially replacing our Adaptive Payments system. PayPal for Marketplaces is live but it is still a limited-release solution. At this time,  the PayPal Partner Team would need to be contacted so your use case can be reviewed by them; ideally, before any development work is done.

Click on the "Contact Us" link at the top of the page listed below to submit a request to our Partner team and they will contact you about your use case.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/